# Filter out the duplicates in PIG

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a records like this.

```
12:-64:12033:24:0:0:1495532058:1384:0:0:0:102
23:-64:8820:24:0:0:1495532126:2788:0:0:0:102
23:-64:8826:24:0:0:1495532132:3064:0:0:0:102
23:-64:8826:24:0:0:1495532132:3065:0:0:0:102
```

I want to filter the duplicate or identical rows in pig.

Note: I dont want to delete or remove the duplicate rows. I need to filter the duplicate rows and store in to one variable.Any help will be appreciated.

```
out1 = GROUP out BY ($1,$7,$11);
records3 = FOREACH out1 {
top_record1 = LIMIT out 1;
final_rec = DISTINCT top_record1;
GENERATE FLATTEN(final_rec);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it.

```
a = load 'file' using PigStorage(':');
b = group a by ($1, $7, $11);
c = foreach b generate flatten(group), COUNT(a) as (cnt: int);
d = filter c by cnt>1;
e = foreach d generate flatten(a) ;
```

Comment: <line 13, column 31> Invalid scalar projection: a : A column needs to be projected from a relation for it to be used as a scalar

Comment: @yico To test for duplicates, I took duplicate rows in your data and modified it a little bit. You are getting this error because there are no duplicates in your data and hence relation `d` is empty.